# How can I publish my open source application immediately using gitub or any other open source websites?

Tags: github, open-source

I have developed an interesting application that I want to publish it as an open source with MIT license.

I found GitHub and other websites to store such an open source applications but the issue is that I can't just upload my application files immediately to one of these websites like GitHub!
They are requesting to setup a local software, connect it then build the files one by one! very long task!

Is there any easier way?

Comment: GitHub isn't really for publishing; it's a remote target for the Git version control system. "Publishing" is mostly a side effect of that main goal. I hope that you've used version control while developing your product? It's likely easiest to use some service that is aware of whatever software you've used.

Comment: @chris it's just initial publishing, my application is working fine, but i am sure about that it still in need for developing process, what do you suggesting?

Comment: If you aren't using any form of version control (e.g. Git, Mercurial, Subversion) you should start immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub being a *source* repository hosting service, you need indeed to commit, and push your sources to a GitHub repo first, and apply a tag.

Then, you would be able to associate a release to that tag: see "[Creating a release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/)"

That would be the part which allows you to publish an "application" (meaning an executable delivery).

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/releases/releases_adding_binary.gif]

The goal is to keep a strong link between:

- a specific version of the source code (through the tag)
- a delivery (built from said sources)

Comment: Thanks, sorry for delay, I don't have an executable delivery! all what I have are the main php files, those needs to be in a localhost to be executed using internet browser in order to get the application. Any suggestions please?